# Consider $F(a)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}{\frac{1}{1+x^a(\ln(1+x)^2f(x)}} \, \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f$ be $T$-periodic, continuous, such that $T=1$, $f(0)=0$, $f'(0)>0$, and $f(x)>0$ for $x\in(0,1)$.

$$F(a) = \int_{0}^{+\infty} {\frac{1}{1+x^a(\ln(1+x))^2f(x)}} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

Consider the domain, continuity, and differentiability of $F(a)$.

This is a question of *Unified National Graduate Entrance Examination* (China). I don't know how to do this problem. So I want to get some help and hint. If I make progress, I will edit it soon.

Thanks. Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

**My attempt**

I think there exists a contradiction.

$$f(0)=f(1)=0,f'(1)=f'(0)>0$$
So $\exists \xi\in(0,1),f(\xi)<0$

This is the picture of question.

[image: This is the picture of question.]

Comment: @SangchulLee I'm sorry.It's $a$.I have edited it.

Comment: And on top of that, what puzzles me is the following observation: If $f$ is 1-periodic, $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)>0$, then there must exist $\delta >0$ such that $f$ is negative on each interval $(n-\delta, n)$ for each $n=1,2,\cdots$. Is every condition stated just as in the original problem?

Comment: A bracket is missing. I have edited it.

Comment: @SangchulLee There is a contradiction in the question.$f'(1)=f'(0)>0,f(1)=f(0)=0$,so $\exists \xi\in(0,1),f(\xi)<0$，Do you think I'm right？

Comment: Yes, I also think that the assumptions are contradictory. Perhaps we can make amends to the problem either by ignoring the condition $f'(0)>0$ or by replacing it by $f'(0^+)>0$.

Comment: And then can you prove it?

Answer (score 1):

Let me first assume that $f$ is continuous, non-negative and $1$-periodic. To study convergence of $F(a)$, we focus on the integral of the form

$$ I_n(a) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1 + n^a \left( \log (n+1) \right)^2 f(x)}. $$

This is related to $F(a)$ by the inequality $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n(a) \leq F(a) \leq 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n(a) $, and so, it suffices to investigate the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n(a)$ instead. To this end, we make extra assumptions:

1. There exist constants $0 < c_1 < C_1$ and $\delta > 0$ such that $c_1 |x| \leq f(x) \leq C_1|x|$ near $x = 0$.
2. $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in (0, 1)$.

Notice that the first condition is more general than the assumption that both the right-derivative $f'(0^+)$ and the left-derivative $f'(0^-)$ exist and are positive. Also, it is easy to check that these two assumptions are equivalent to the following single condition:

- There exist constants $0 < c_2 < C_2$ such that $c_2|x| \leq f(x) \leq C_2|x|$ for all $|x| \leq \frac{1}{2}$.

From this, we obtain bounds

$$
I_n(a)
\geq 2\int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1 + n^a \left( \log(n+1) \right)^2 C_2x}
= \frac{2\log\left(1 + (C_2/2) n^a \left( \log(n+1) \right)^2 \right)}{n^a \left( \log(n+1) \right)^2}
$$

and

$$
I_n(a)
\leq 2\int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1 + n^a \left( \log(n+1) \right)^2 c_2x}
= \frac{2\log\left(1 + (c_2/2) n^a \left( \log(n+1) \right)^2 \right)}{n^a \left( \log(n+1) \right)^2}
$$

From this, we find that there exist constants $0 < c_3 < C_3 $, possibly depending only on $a$, such that

$$ \frac{c_3}{n^a \log(n+1)} \leq I_n(a) \leq \frac{C_3}{n^a \log(n+1)}. $$

Therefore $F(a)$ converges if and only if $a > 1$.

Once the convergence is established, continuity of $F$ on $(1, \infty)$ is an easy consequence of the dominated convergence theorem. Differentiability is a bit more cumbersome to establish, but we can indeed prove that $F$ is differentiable on $(1, \infty)$.

Comment: Can you tell me some hint about how to prove the differentiability of $F$?

Comment: @LiTaichi, Although not impossible, working directly with the differential quotient is not easy. Rather, you can show that $$G(a):=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\left(\frac{1}{1+x^a\left(\log(1+x)\right)^2f(x)}\right) \,\mathrm{d}x$$ exists as continuous function on $(1, \infty)$ (which is pretty much the same as in my answer, given appropriate assumptions on $f$) and that $$ F(b) - F(a) = \int_{a}^{b} G(x) \, \mathrm{d}x. $$ for $1 <a < b$, for instance, by using Fubini's theorem. This is enough to show that $F$ is differentiable with $F' = G$.

Comment: Thanks, I have a general idea.But if you are free,you could write it down.@Sangchui Lee