# Prove $\frac{m(1-m)}{n}+1\leq\frac{n^m-m^m}{x^m}\leq m(1-m)+n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inequality, contest-math

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{m}x^m+\frac{1}{n}-x$,such that $\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}=1(n>m>1),x\in[m,n],f(x)\geq0 $

Prove that:

$$\frac{m(1-m)}{n}+1\leq\frac{n^m-m^m}{x^m}\leq m(1-m)+n$$

This is a question of Unified National Graduate Entrance Examination(China). I don't know how to do this problem. So I want to get some help and hint. If I make progress，I will edit it soon.

Thanks. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the mean value theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: We have $$\frac{f(n)-f(m)}{n-m}=\frac{\xi^{m-1}m}{m}-1$$ so
$$\frac{\frac{n^m-m^m}{m}+m-n}{(n-m)}=\frac{n^m-m^m}{m(n-m)}-1$$ and use that $$n=\frac{m}{m-1}$$
Doing this we get
$$n^m-m^m\le x^{m-1}m(n-m)\le x^mm(n-m)$$ (since $$x>1$$)
So we get
$$\frac{n^m-m^m}{x^m}\le m(n-m)=m(1-m)+n$$ we have only to show that
$$mn\le m+n$$ this is (substituting $$n=\frac{m}{m-1}$$)
we get
$$\frac{m}{m-1}\le 1 +\frac{1}{m-1}$$ this is true since $$m\le m-1+1$$
Similary we can show the lower bound!
($\xi \in [m,n]$)

We have $$\frac{n^m-m^m}{m(n-m)}=\xi^{m-1}\le x^{m-1}\le x^m$$ since $$\xi \in [m,n]$$ and $$x>1$$

Comment: thanks you.This answer is so good!

Comment: Can you send me more such problems?

Comment: It is a good training for my students.

Comment: I don't know what kind of problem you need.questionMaybe this question is suitable for your student. @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner

Comment: Could you please write more detail?How do you get $n^m-m^m\le x^{m-1}m(n-m)$?And how do you get the lower bound?@Dr. Sonnhard Graubner

Comment: I have written this above, please read it carefully.

Comment: I get it!Thank you!em... could you please help me solve another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3121280/consider-fa-int-0-infty-frac11xa-ln1x2fx-mathrmdx?noredirect=1#comment6431098_3121280)?

Comment: For the lower bound i need the condition $$2>m$$

Comment: $m>2$, exchange $n$ and $m$,

Comment: Ok this is possible